# Jquery - Access DIV inside a td tag

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble accessing a div element within a table.

```
// All within document ready ...

$('.ChangeStatus').click(function()
{
    $('#status_display:100').html('Updated');   

});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<td>
     <div class="status_display" id="status_display:100">
          open<br/>
          <a href="#" class="ChangeStatus" id="close:100">Close lead</a>
     </div>
</td>
```

WHen I click the anchor it says the html of the div is null before and after I try to set the html.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

The : character is a [special character in jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which needs to be escaped.

Try this `$('#status_display\\:100').html('Updated');`

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could escape them like that.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has problems with IDs that contain colons:

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Thank you sir works perfectly.  Did not know that jQuery had issues with colons as ids.